# python backtracking on a dictionary

Tags: list, function, dictionary

So, I've got a total of `n` questions, each questions have some points.

I have to create all possible sets of questions that have between `u` and `v` questions and between `x` and `y` points accumulated, and I have to do that using backtracking.

For this I thought about using a dictionary, e.g: questions = {"Q1":5, "Q2":3, "Q3": 4, "Q4" : 10, "Q5" : 6, "Q6" : 7}, so there are 6 questions, first question ("Q1") has 5 points and so on

I started coding but I don't know how to create the backtracking function itself, I don't understand how to go through all possibilities if that makes sense.

```
questions = {"Q1":5, "Q2":3, "Q3": 4, "Q4" : 10, "Q5" : 6, "Q6" : 7}
u = 3  #
v = 5 # between u and v questions


x = 5   #
y = 100 #between x and y points


def get_points(ar):
    s = 0
    for key, value in ar.items():
        s = s + int(value)
    return s


def get_NOQuestions(ar):
    return len(ar)



def reject(candidate):
    if (get_points(candidate) > y and get_NOQuestions(candidate) < v) or (get_NOQuestions(candidate) >= v and get_points(candidate) < x):
        return False
    return True



def accept(candidate):
    if get_points(candidate) >= x and get_points (candidate) <= y and get_NOQuestions(candidate) >= u and get_NOQuestions(candidate) <= v:
        return True
    return False



def output(candidate):
    print(candidate)



ar = {}

def backtracking(k):
    for key, value in questions.items():
        ar[key] = value
        if not reject(ar):
            if accept(ar):
                output(ar)
            else:
                backtracking(k+1)

backtracking(0)
```

This is what I've got so far, obviously the 'backtracking' function does not work because it doesn't go through all possibilities (not that it should in this form, it's just a for)

I'm thinking of maybe permuting all items in the dictionary (permutation of length between `u` and `v`) and get those that satisfy the conditions in the 'accept' function, but for sure there is a smarter way to do it.

Answer (score 0):

You need to rewrite the logic of your `reject()` and `accept()` function because your code will never reach to `if accept(ar)` with your given input. Try to run your code in paper and you will figure it out.

I also suggest refactoring `get_points(arr)` to something like this:

```
def get_points(arr):
    return sum(arr.values())
```

Less logic == less bugs.

Comment: So you're saying the actual backtracking function itself goes through all possibilities, is just my accept and reject functions that are bad? Because I doubt that's the case

Thanks for the suggestion btw :)